# shasum check failed for installing phone gap using npm

Tags: html, node.js, cordova, npm

I have tried for many times but still this error (shasum check failed)

```
4784 error Error: shasum check failed for C:\Users\FENGXI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-7004-QbpFFte5\1387269030233-0.28223602287471294\tmp.tgz
4784 error Expected: dee5a33ff04d7217194dc1ad1342e3a441761942
4784 error Actual:   ab7d89ca1f31db14db047d01222dd968649cfb50
4784 error     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha\index.js:38:8
4784 error     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha\index.js:85:7)
4784 error     at ReadStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
4784 error     at _stream_readable.js:920:16
4784 error     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
4785 error If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
4785 error including the npm and node versions, at:
4785 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
4786 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
4787 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
4788 error cwd D:\environment\phonegap
4789 error node -v v0.10.23
4790 error npm -v 1.3.17
```

Comment: Clean and re-download.

Comment: Same error here both with Phonegap and Cordova.

Comment: If my answer did help you, please check as accepted :)

Comment: It realy works , Thank you!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The root cause of this is fixed.  Please **do not** take the advice in this thread and hack your way around checksum errors, ever.  If something has a busted checksum, it's not to be trusted.  At best, it's broken; at worst, it's maliciously hacked.  Either way, it's not a good sign, and the error is the system working.

Comment: So how to solve the problem ? This way , I could not install phoneGap using npm~~

Comment: See my comment below. Standalone download is passing the check.

Answer (score 14):

Just had the same issue.
Type:

```
$ npm install [URL]
```

with the URL right before the shasum check fails.
After that run your install command again and everything should go on.

eg. for Cordova it was:

```
$ npm install https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.19.tgz
```

Comment: Oh dear sweet zombie jesus don't do this!  If the shasum check failed, think about what that means?  At *best* that tarball is a broken version of npm. At worst, it's corrupted, perhaps maliciously.  The error is the system working, and preventing you from getting bogus bits.  (In this case, yes, it's a bug, and it's since been fixed.)  Please tell everyone you know to never ever disregard checksum failures.

Comment: But in this case it obviously happens because of a timeout while downloading and a corrupted package will fail the check for sure. The standalone download is passing the check. No need to worry ;)

Comment: @clash No, in this case, the cause was that npm had a bug causing publishes to be made with the incorrect shasum. Since I use npm to publish itself, it was the first package affected. If you install this version of npm, every package you publish with it will have the wrong shasum!  That's awful!

Answer (score 4):

As @isaacs says mostly it will mean a corrupt package. In my case that was not the issue. What it worked for me was:

First, try:

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

and re-install what you was trying to install

---

Another workaround, use the npm mirror:

```
npm set registry http://ec2-46-137-149-160.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

you can reset this later with

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

then use it normally:

npm install [...]

---

Note: thanks to `hassanmaher` in https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2701#issuecomment-40927831

Answer (score 2):

Just reinstall, sometimes due to network problem. Once any module pack is uncompleted, shasum error will be throw. Please reinstall until successes.

Answer (score 0):

try: npm install https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-1.3.21.tgz

change from "19" to "21"